# What is paster and how do I install it?

Tags: python, paster

I am installing an application and have installed `python` and `easy_install`. I now have two steps to complete:

```
5. Make a config file as follows::

    paster make-config openbiblio development.ini

6. Tweak the config file as appropriate and then setup the application::

    paster setup-app config.ini
```

I have read Stackoverflow answers and tried the web but cannot find installation instructions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're looking for [pythonpaste](https://pastescript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)'s "Paste Script", which you can download from [pypi.python.org](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PasteScript) and then unpack and install.

Comment: I'm still confused - the site you mention has `paste  create --template=basic_package MyPackage` rather than `paster`. I'll try it out

Comment: @peter, now I'm also confused (by what you say;-)...: at http://pythonpaste.org/script/ I see `paster serve --help` etc -- where do you see it spelled without the trailing `r` in that page?

Comment: First thanx! On `http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PasteScript` it says what I have written. I have now unpacked it, tried to install it (I am a newbie) with `easy_install PasteScript-1.7.3` and it says it is installed. There is now a paster.exe in the Python Scripts which I will try out

Comment: You're right, looks like a typo in the `pypi` page -- unfortunately I don't know how to warn the page maintainer of that!

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt-get install python-pastescript
```